# Find the following $\overline{\overline{C}}$ and $\overline{\overline{A\cup C}}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Find the following $\overline{\overline{C}}$ and $\overline{\overline{A\cup C}}$

Could anyone show me how to approach these kind of problems ?

$\overline{\overline{A}}= 24 ,\overline{\overline{B}}= 21 ,\overline{\overline{A\cup B}}= 37 , \overline{\overline{A\cap C}}= 11 , \overline{\overline{B-C}}= 10 ,\overline{\overline{C-B}}= 12$

Comment: I've never seen the notation $\overline{\overline C}$. Can you explain it?

Comment: My guess is this means $|C|$.

Comment: @Thomas: Slightly old-fashioned notation for cardinality, still used in some contexts (thought not usually at this elementary level).

Comment: @ThomasAndrews it's the same as $\|C|$ like vadimi123 said.

Comment: this a Q of arithmetic

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ve numbered the seven bounded regions in the Venn diagram below; let $n_k$ be the cardinality of region $k$. Then we’re told the following:

$$\left\{\begin{align*}
&n_1+n_4+n_5+n_7=24\\
&n_2+n_5+n_6+n_7=21\\
&n_1+n_2+n_4+n_5+n_6+n_7=37\\
&n_4+n_7=11\\
&n_2+n_5=10\\
&n_3+n_4=12
\end{align*}\right.\tag{1}$$

[image]

We want $|C|=n_3+n_4+n_6+n_7$.

From the second and fifth equations of $(1)$ we can infer that $n_6+n_7=21-10=11$; combining this with the last equation of $(1)$, we have

$$|C|=n_3+n_4+n_6+n_7=12+11=23\;.$$

A similar approach will give you $|A\cup C|$.

Comment: I just noticed that I made a mistake equation, it should've been $\overline{\overline{C-B}}=12$.

Comment: @Kururugi: That affects the specific answer, but not the method.

Comment: I just noticed that I made a mistake equation, it should've been $\overline{\overline{C-B}}=12$. For the first question I got $|C|= 23$. How did you know how to set-up the venn diagram for the problem? It looks like for example since you have $|A|= |A-B|+ |A\cap B$| then there is a n_{k} in there interception, is that how it works?

Comment: @Kururugi: First I looked to see whether there was some relatively trivial solution. Not finding one, I broke the Venn diagram for $3$ sets into its component regions and rewrote the given data in terms of those regions. The result was six equations in seven unknowns. Had worst come to worst, I could have solved that system for six of the unknowns in terms of the seventh and then looked for some way to eliminate the last unknown. Before going to all that work, however, I looked to see what $|C|$ was in terms of my seven unknowns; when it turned out to be a combination of known values, ...

Comment: ... I was home free. Then I checked to see that $|A\cup C|$ was equally accessible, and sure enough, it was. Breaking $A\cup B\cup C$ into its basic components is a natural thing to do, because from those pieces you can get all of the Boolean combinations like $A\cap C$, $B\setminus A$, etc. Conversely, you can (as I did) break the given information into statements about the basic pieces, which you can then manipulate to get more information.

Comment: Thanks for the advice though. For the last equation I got that $|AuC|=36$

Comment: @Kururugi: Yes, that’s what I get as well. From the first and fourth equations of $(1)$ I got $n_1+n_5=13$, and adding that to $|C|$ gives the result. (There may be other routes, but that’s how I did it.)

Comment: I think your way is faster than mine since I got it by breaking down $\overline{\overline{A\cup C}}$ into $\overline{\overline{A}}+\overline{\overline{B}}-\overline{\overline{A\cap C}}$ then we know that $\overline{\overline{A}}=24$, $\overline{\overline{C}}$ and $\overline{\overline{A\cap B}}=11$.